# Multiple Backbonejs requests to get related model data

Tags: django, django-models, backbone.js, tastypie

I built a RESTful API with these two resources (with tastypie) :

```
class PhotographerResource(ModelResource):
    album = fields.ToManyField('core.api.AlbumResource', 'album_set')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Photographer.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'photographer'
        authorization = Authorization()


class AlbumResource(ModelResource):

    artist = fields.ForeignKey(PhotographerResource, 'photographer', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Album.objects.all()
        resource_name= 'albums'
        authorization = Authorization()
```

Now when I access `/api/v1/albums/1` I get the following result:

```
{
"album": ["/api/v1/albums/4/", "/api/v1/albums/5/"],
"photographer_name": "Jimi Hendrix",
"photographer_thumbnail": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Katatonia_in_2004.jpg/300px-Katatonia_in_2004.jpg",
"biography": "Jimmi Hendrix is an awesome musician man...",
"id": "1",
"page_link": "http://ahmetkaya.com/",
"resource_uri": "/api/v1/artists/1/",
"slug": "jimi-hendrix"
}
```

Now in my front end which is Backbonejs, when I want to get the albums of the photographer, I'll have to create an `album` object, `fetch` the data from the server to render it in the view. Now my question is, won't this method (sending many requests to the server) slow down the loading of the page and negatively affect the UX and app performance? Is there a better way to design the relations between my resources?
Or, is it better to replace the RESTful API with Django views that handle `save` and `fetch`, or this isn't the "proper" way to do it? I would like to follow the conventions and best practices when I'm learning, but Backbonejs seems to have no conventions really..

Thanks

Comment: ` I'll have to create an album object, fetch the data from the server to render it in the view. ` Yup this will slow down but here is the point. User won't be interested in seeing all the album photographs would he? just when he is playing the one from the list. You have to implement clever UI so that user has to switch between two views to view the artist and the photograph

Answer (score 1):

On the backbone side you can create an Album collection and set its url to /api/v1/albums and call fetch on the collection. This will pull all of the albums in one http request. url can also be a function if you need to provide filtering via something like /api/v1/albums/byname/jonathancoulton or /api/v1/albums/bytitle/codemonkey. I have also set up custom fetch functions on a collection if you use this functionality a lot

Comment: Aha ! But how do I do the filtering in the Resource? I'm new to Tastypie by the way. This method sounds optimal, but fetching aaaalll of the albums isn't a good idea, imagine i have 2000 albums, soo..

Comment: I don't know Tastypie, but in django you would set up the route in your urls.py file. It should be similar to the way you set up the /api/{version}/albums/{id} route. /api/{version}/albums/byname/{name}.

Comment: But is it a good idea to replace the REST api with views? For me it's easier to manipulate, but I'm not sure if Backbone.js "allows" me to do that.

Comment: Backbone is quite flexible. That is why the url property that is used for fetching can either be a string or a function that returns a string. Personally I think of the REST provided by a Resource as scaffolding. It works for 80% but sometimes I need more than what is provided. Like filtering.

Comment: So to my understanding, i can leave the REST as it is, and add Django views for "special" cases? As I can change the model/collection's url anytime?

Comment: Yep. Definitely leave the Resource generated REST there so you don't have to write it :) Then supplement with what you need for an efficient app.